# Jquery hide class show individual div

Tags: jquery

I have a list of divs that are dynamically generated and looks like the following

```
<div class="Foo">
  <div class ="Bar" id ="Something{X}">  // Where {X} is a counter i.e "Something1" , "Something2"
  <p>some stuff</p>
  <form>
    <input />
  </form>
</div>
```

Now after I dynamically generate all my div's of class foo I do the following

```
$('.Foo').hide();
```

Which obviously hides all the div's like I'd expect.  However, what I'd like is the ability to click on a link above the div that allows you to unhide that individual div.

Now normally for a class I know I'd just go $('.Foo').show();  and they would ALL show.

However, doing the following does not work.

```
$("#Something1").show();
```

Is this something that is allowed by jQuery to hide everything and then show individual items?  Or am I going about this wrong?

Comment: Your HTML seems to be missing a close Div tag (for one or another, its hard to say).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are hiding the parent container, which is staying hidden.

Try hiding your "bars" instead

`$('.bar').hide();`

and then `$("something1").show()`

Answer (score 1):

You are hiding the parent div with the class foo; therefore, you need to show that div instead.

```
$("#Something1").parent().show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
$(".foo").hide();
```

It should be:

```
$(".bar").hide();
```

And then reopen one by:

```
$("#Something1").show();
```

You were hiding the parent container and then trying to open one of its children, so you could not see it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p class="showlink">Link to show</p>
<div class="Foo">
  <div class ="Bar" id ="Something{X}">  // Where {X} is a counter i.e "Something1" , "Something2"
  <p>some stuff</p>
  <form>
    <input />
  </form>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(".showlink").on('click', function() {
    $(this).next('.Foo').show();
});
```